# In GTA V, Get away car won't spawn

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have failed the mission multiple times, thinking that would work, and it still doesn't appear. I don't remember the car, but the location was apparently a ally in Mirror Park. According to the game, the car is parked in someone's back yard. Is there any way to spawn a new car labeled as the get away? (I've also quit the game, and redone the entire heist and nothing has happened)

The heist where this is happening is the one where you get the Intel from the FIB about the Union Depository.